# Multiple webdatarocks pivot on same page Exception DisplayGrids

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

Multiple Webdatarocks pivots gives exception

> "is not a constructor at displaygrids"

script is included properly but no resolution.. There is also & issue on how to differentiate export of data for both grids separately when on the same page.

Following is the code :

```
'''
function displaygrids(parsed_data,parsed_data_2) {

  var pivot = new webdatarocks({
    container: "#d1-component",
    //toolbar: true,
    //  beforetoolbarcreated: customizeToolbar,
    //height: 295,
    report: {
      dataSource: {

        data: parsed_data,
            }
         }
   });


  var p1= new webdatarocks({
          container: "#d2-component",
          //toolbar: true,
          //  beforetoolbarcreated: customizeToolbar,
          //height: 295,
          report: {
            dataSource: {

              data: parsed_data_2,
                }
            }
        });
  }
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a reference to the WebDataRocks thread with a similar question - https://www.webdatarocks.com/question/how-to-put-pivottable-in-bootstrap-grid/    .

They placed 2 WebDataRocks in a row with a help of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful but the challenge is identifying exporttoexcel or pdf how to differentiate between two pivots? Pivot1.exportto('excel')?

Comment: Referring to the sample in the thread, pivot1.exportTo("pdf"); - will export the first pivot and pivot2.exportTo("pdf"); - will export the second one. You can add 2 buttons with the appropriate handlers to check it.

Comment: This is accurate. This has helped in resolving the issue with print functionality.